# testing for the color red

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, slick2d

I am attempting to write a collision map for an old school RPG.  I created an Image using the color red (255, 0, 0) where collisions should occur and am trying to test for when my sprites positions (x, y) will turn up as red on the collision map.  Here is my code that won't seem to work:

```
public boolean isBlocked(int testX, int testY) {

    System.out.println(collisionMap.getColor(testX, testY)); //debug
    System.out.println(Color.red); //debug

    if ((collisionMap.getColor(testX, testY)) == Color.red) {
            System.out.println("COLLISION OCCURRING!"); //debug
            return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("NO COLLISION OCCURRING!"); //debug
        return false;
    }
}
```

When a collision should be occurring, I get the following output in my console:

Color (1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)

Color (1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)

NO COLLISION OCCURRING!

For some reason the If statement isn't picking up the two values to be equal, even though they appear to be.

Comment: They aren't enums, use .equals()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because Color.red is an object, not a value. Try using

```
collisionMap.getColor(textX, testY).equals(Color.red)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code might be comparing object references via ==.  Perhaps replace the comparison with:

```
if ((collisionMap.getColor(testX, testY)).equals(Color.red))
```

Also, make sure you have equals() properly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is if you are using `java.awt.Color;` for your color objects..
When I output them, I get `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]` instead of `Color (1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)` like you.

Try replacing this line:

```
if ( ( collisionMap.getStringColor( 0 , 0 ) ).equalsIgnoreCase( Color.red.toString() ) )
```

I created a stand alone where I have it working:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        CollisionMap collisionMap = new CollisionMap();

        System.out.println( collisionMap.getStringColor( 0 , 0 ) );
        System.out.println( collisionMap.getColorColor( 0 , 0 ) );

        if ( ( collisionMap.getStringColor( 0 , 0 ) ).equalsIgnoreCase( Color.red.toString() ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "COLLISION OCCURRING!" ); // debug
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "NO COLLISION OCCURRING!" ); // debug
        }
    }

    public static class CollisionMap
    {
        public Color getColorColor( Integer x , Integer y )
        {
            return Color.red;
        }

        public String getStringColor( Integer x , Integer y )
        {
            return Color.red.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
COLLISION OCCURRING!
```